# MySQL Workbench not showing table properly

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image]

So when I downloaded the MySQL and used workbench, it shows like this so I could not edit the data type here, which is different from others. I have tried reinstalled MySQL and workbench yet the problem remains.

Can someone point out what's going wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: have you logged in with relevant permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression introduced when the details pane had been made visible in modeling too (it is always visible in the SQL IDE). With the next update the default height for the table editor will be increased so that you can see the columns table immediately. Of course you can always resize the editor (there is a splitter right above the editor, which you can drag for resizing).

Comment: Wow thank you so much Mike! Surprisingly this problem cost me 2 hours    -_- Thanks again..